# Selecting fields that are not in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am working with group by in SQL Server. I want to select fields that shouldn't be part of group by.

I want to select ***DishId*** but it shouldn't be in group by clause. If I add the DishId into group by it repeats the range as shown following.

[image: Output of following query is here]

```
SELECT  v.range, COUNT(*) AS 'occurrences',COUNT(DishID) * SUM(OrderQty) AS [TotalOrders],po.DishID 
  FROM ( SELECT PgrId,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, p.PgrDOB, GETDATE()) >= 0  AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, p.PgrDOB, GETDATE()) < 10 THEN '0-9'   
                     WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, p.PgrDOB, GETDATE()) >= 10 AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, p.PgrDOB, GETDATE()) < 20 THEN '10-19'   
                     WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, p.PgrDOB, GETDATE()) >= 20 AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, p.PgrDOB, GETDATE()) < 30 THEN '20-29'   
                     WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, p.PgrDOB, GETDATE()) >= 30 AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, p.PgrDOB, GETDATE()) < 40 THEN '30-39'   
                     ELSE '40+' 
                END AS 'range'  
               FROM Passenger p 
              ) v inner join PassengerOrder po on v.PgrId  = po.PgrID   
 GROUP BY v.range,po.DishID
```

Comment: Is this your complete code, because it starts with from not select. also, I don't see any aggregation happening in your select, so you don't need a group by clause, if you are not performing any aggregation operation then use distinct in select, it will give you the grouped(unique) values.

Comment: @MoulitharanM Can you now check . I have update the query

Comment: Is the range repeating because there are _different_ values of `DishID`? If you don't want a different row for each `range/DishID` combination, then you need to decide which `DishID` value you want. You can use `MIN` or MAX` or other things like `FIRST_VALUE` but you can't just add it to the `GROUP BY` if you don't want all the distinct values. Create a [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle) with some sample data and explain which `DishID` you want to show for `40+` and why.

Comment: You can either select a single value: first, last, some other criteria. Or you can aggregate all the values using `STRING_AGG`

Comment: here is the dbFiddle link 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d7eee56b6f242b159c0bcd5502060ef

Comment: I want to know which age group buys which dish the most. for example youngster like the dish0001 the most. old people like dish0003 the most etc

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Something like this basically https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3d37659713c6d8db70d671fa832079f6. I must say, `COUNT(DishID) * SUM(OrderQty)` looks a bit suspect, firstly `COUNT(DishID)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`, also logically you would just need `SUM(OrderQty)` if you wanted total orders

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want the highest dish in each age range, ordered by total sales descending. There are many other improvements that could be made here but the simplest way is to just generate a row number per range ordered by total sales descending, and wrap that in a CTE, filtered by the first row number.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT v.range, 
   COUNT(*) AS occurrences,
   COUNT(DishID) * SUM(OrderQty) AS TotalOrders,
   po.DishID,
   rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.range 
        ORDER BY COUNT(DishID) * SUM(OrderQty) DESC)
  FROM 
  ( SELECT PgrId,
    CASE WHEN p.PgrDOB < DATEADD(YEAR, -40, GETDATE()) THEN '40+'
         WHEN p.PgrDOB < DATEADD(YEAR, -30, GETDATE()) THEN '30-39'
         WHEN p.PgrDOB < DATEADD(YEAR, -20, GETDATE()) THEN '20-29'
         WHEN p.PgrDOB < DATEADD(YEAR, -10, GETDATE()) THEN '10-19'
         ELSE '0-9'
    END AS range
    FROM dbo.Passenger p    
 ) v inner join dbo.PassengerOrder po on v.PgrId  = po.PgrID    
 GROUP BY v.range,po.DishID 
)
SELECT range, occurrences, TotalOrders, DishID
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
  ORDER BY TotalOrders DESC;
```

Output (shown in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c8801e45675592e0de0587f7f22144d6)):

| range | occurrences | TotalOrders | DishID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40+ | 2 | 220 | dsh0000001 |
| 30-39 | 2 | 84 | dsh0000001 |
| 10-19 | 1 | 11 | dsh0000001 |
| 20-29 | 1 | 1 | dsh0000001 |
| 0-9 | 1 | 1 | dsh0000001 |

I fixed a couple of other things, too:

- [Always use schema name for objects](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).
- Don't use `'single quotes'` to delimit column aliases; this makes them too easy to confuse with string literals. Use `[square brackets]` instead, but don't delimit at all unless you need to. (I talk a little about that [here](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases).)
- Your `DATEDIFF` calculation was not accurate to a person's birthday, nor is mine, but if you flip the order you can make a much less complex CASE expression, and when you move functions away from the column, you make it more likely that the query could benefit from a current (or future) index. Lots more at [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates).